# Как запустить cmd через Qt (QProcess) со своими параметрами

Tags: c++, qt, cmd, qprocess

Пытаюсь запустить cmd со своими параметрами из qt, использую QProcess.

Мой код:

```
    QString program = "C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "java";
    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
    myProcess->startDetached(program, arguments);

    if (!myProcess->waitForStarted())
    {
        qDebug() << "1: " +myProcess->readAllStandardOutput();
        qDebug() << "2: " +myProcess->readAllStandardError();
        qDebug() << "The process didnt start" << myProcess->error();
    }
```

Выводиться такие сообщения об ошибке:

```
QIODevice::read (QProcess): device not open
"1: "
QIODevice::read (QProcess): device not open
"2: "
The process didnt start QProcess::ProcessError(UnknownError)
```

Пробовал заменить :

```
myProcess->startDetached(program, arguments);
```

на команду:

```
start(...)
```

но один и тот же результат.

Пробовал запустить даже так:

```
    QProcess pro(this);
    pro.start("cmd");
```

но выводиться сообщение:

```
QProcess: Destroyed while process ("cmd") is still running.
```

и cmd не запускается и не появляется.

Подскажите как можно исправить и запустить cmd со своими параметрами? Может быть можно отказаться от QProcess и использовать что-то еще? Или есть какой-то другой подход в этом вопросе? Есть какие-то мысли на этот счет?

Comment: ¿Может вы на самом деле хотите запустить java?

Comment: Да, хочу запустить jar файл через cmd, чтобы высветилось cmd с началом выполнения jar приложения, что думаете?

Comment: Если собираетесь читать стандартные потоки, то запускайте напрямую, т.е. без cmd.

Comment: Как понять фразу - запустить напрямую? Через что получается запуск делать?

Comment: Ну имя программы должно быть java.exe

Comment: ну java.exe это Runtime от java, а мне нужно открыть мое приложение написанное на java, в файле jar, как тогда его напрямую открыть через qt?

Comment: Так для исполнения jar файлов необходимо запустить рантайм java и указать ему, какой jar файл выполнить.

Comment: Ну так все равно запуск будет через qt QProcess, в start пропишем эту java.exe, получается это вы имеет ввиду? Или как еще запустить?

Comment: Именно так, а cmd.exe не нужно.

Comment: Но при это мне нужно, чтобы высветилось, что-то типо cmd, после запуска этого jar файла, чтобы следить за процессом работы jar файла по логам из cmd

Comment: Так вы же потом хотите читать вывод програмно. Если создать окно cmd, то вывод будет попадать в консольный буфер.

Comment: Мне важно чтобы jar запустился и что-то выдавал в этом своем консольном окне, при этом, если я закрою qt, чтобы сразу закрыть и эту cmd с этой jar. А не всмысле запустить, чтобы считывать данные работы jar